# Robocopy for Windows 2003 doesn't support /DST option

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, dst, robocopy

Does anyone know if it is possible to download the latest robocopy for Windows 2003. The latest version provides the /DST option which ignores time stamps changed due to BST (British Summer Time). Every time we do a build and sync our servers when we go +1/-1 hour it takes hours instead of minutes because it sees everything as changed.

I noticed it is included automatically with Vista/Win7 but the Resource toolkit that I downloaded doesn't include a new version of robocopy for Win Server 2003. If there is a place to download it from & will it also work on Windows Server 2003?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Robocopy that comes with Vista is called XP027 and has file version 5.1.10.1027. The version that is included in Windows 2003 Resource Kit is called XP010 (file version 5.1.1.1010).

The solution: Download [Robocopy GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx). It includes XP026 (file version 5.1.2600.26). As of version XP026 Robocopy has /DST option.

Find an [overview on Robocopy versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Versions) on Wikipedia.